# QRegExp containing line feed, enter 

Tags: c++, qt, qregexp

I have no clue how to use `QRegExp`. I am trying to remove selected characters from `QString` but don't know how to write it as regular expression, never worked with those :( I want to remove all line feeds, enters, `|`, `¦`, `¶` and `§`.

Thanks

Ps: I wish to use `QString & QString::remove ( const QRegExp & rx )` and not `QString & QString::remove ( const QString & str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive )` several times.

Comment: I understand you can group characters with [], the problem is character 13 - enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mystring.remove(QRegExp("[\\n\\r|\xA6\xB6\xA7]"));` (untested)

Comment: Will test it today! Ty for replay.